Is it possible to publish two project of the same solution in the same folder?
I have a solution with two projects. One is a windows services and the other is a WPF application that allows to configure the windows services application.
I would like to publish both applications in the same folder.
Is it possible to do it?
I know in the first publish I am prompted to choose where to deploy the project, so in theory I could choose the same folder for both projects, but I don't know if this could be a problem or not.
Thanks.

Yes, it is possible to publish both applications to the same folder. However, you need to make sure that both application have unique name for their executable files and other associated files to prevent conflicts. But why?

Yes it's possible.
I do have a solution with 3 projects [.NET 8] [WPF] [Windows Service] [Console]. They were deployed as self-contained and bundled together using Wix toolset resulting as a large msi package for distribution.
After publishing to the same folder, the app size reduced to about a third; obviously due to shared .NET8 dll files.
The only caveat, as @Double E has stated in comments, is that of name conflicts. I in particular had issues with the appsettings.json files of the Windows Service getting overwritten by that of the Console App. Which was because the Console App was the last in the build process. I resolved that by making sure the appsettings of the other apps are copied to that of the Console App.
I've had no issues with running and execution so far.
